# Cannot Traverse in Window Mode Exception

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I'm working with Guidewire (GOSU) and I noticed there is not much information on the internet for this language. Trying my luck here.

I am creating a GX Model in guidewire studio and i am trying to map a property. But I keep getting an exception saying:

> Exception stack trace: gw.xml.gx.GxException: Could not map property
>   PolicyContactRoles[]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot traverse in
>   window mode

Does anyone have an idea on what this exception means?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen at multiple points in the Guidewire application. It has been seen in both configuration and integration code. All objects in PolicyCenter can either be in slice or window mode.

**Slice** - Contains the version of the object at a specific point in time, such as the effective date of the job. This is the mode that most people interact with.

**Window** - Contains the data for all the versions of the object for the life of the policy term.

There are many functions in the system that assumes we are running in slice mode. Each of these functions will throw the Illegal Argument Exception. To fix this, we need to find the PolicyPeriod. This may be in the current method or we may need to look in calling functions or traverse the entity model. We can then use the

`getSlice(thePropertyYouNeedToMap)`

method to get the slice that is effective on that particular field.

Hope this clarifies for your question.